# Visual studio 2019 high usage of memory

Tags: memory, visual-studio-2019, disk

I installed win10 and the visual studio community 2019 last week. But today when I check the space of C disk, I realize it just has 7.6G free. I haven't installed anything since last week, and copied anything.I also checked task manager, I saw the visual studio were using a lot of memory. So I think the visual studio is the reason that make c full.
Do I think right?Do I have way to 'fix' the visual to make it dont use a lot of memory?and How

Comment: Hi, have you tried debugging by closing files and uninstalling plugins? Could also be AV.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed. Can you give me another idea? I don't know how to make my visual studio not use 5-8G for just one time using.